# How to call a function of this type

Tags: c++

> /* Write a function that returns the length of a string(char *), excluding the ﬁnal NULL
>    character.It should not use any standard - library functions.You may use arithmetic and
>   dereference operators, but not the indexing operator ([]) */

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int stringLength(const char * str) {

int length = 0;

 while (*(str + length) != '\0') {

 ++length;

    cout << length;

return length;

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

stringLength({ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' });

return 0;
}
```

Somehow I think I am not calling my function properly in the main function, but I am not sure how else I should do it. What is the proper way of calling a function of this type? (Sorry if this is a stupid question: I am new to C++)

Comment: `int len = stringLength("abc");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like: `int l = stringLength("abc");`

C constant strings are automatically zero terminated, so you don't need to specify the extra zero character.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a string. For instance

```
int len = stringLength("abc");
```

FWIW, it would be idiomatic to use `size_t` for the return type of this function. When you try to work with other code you'll meet resistance to having used `int` rather than `size_t`.

The code in the question is also rather poorly formatted and does not compile. You omitted a closing brace. It pays to get this sort of detail just right.